# webpack + mobx + React : require an observable array of images

Tags: arrays, image, webpack, mobx-react

I am using mobX to store arrays of images for a gallery like this :

```
@observable peopleThumb = [
'src/assets/photos/people/thumbs_1.jpg',
'src/assets/photos/people/thumbs_2.jpg',
'src/assets/photos/people/thumbs_3.jpg',
etc...
]
```

Where I have my thumbnails array, the full images array and the mobile images array.

Then I map through the array and use them either as background images or in an image tag in my components (urls are passed down via props) :

```
<img src={url} />
or
background: `url(${url}) no-repeat center center`,
```

But when I build for prod since the images are not required and the urls stays like src/assets/photos/people/' they obviously won't be displayed

So I tried simply requiring them :

```
<img src={require(url)}/>
and
background: `url(${require(url)}) no-repeat center center`
```

But I get an error :

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'src/assets/photos/people/full_3.jpg'.
```

I tried changing the path in my store to a relative path :

```
@observable peopleThumb = [
'../assets/photos/people/thumbs_1.jpg',
'../assets/photos/people/thumbs_2.jpg',
'../assets/photos/people/thumbs_3.jpg',
etc...
]
```

And same error :

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../assets/photos/people/full_2.jpg'.
```

My webpack config for my output and the file loader :

```
  output: {
   path: "./build/",
   filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
   chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'file',
    query: {
      name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    }
  },
```

When I import single images via Import everything works fine but I am stuck when it comes to this observable. I also tried the require context but I honestly didn't really understood what I was doing and I think I should be able to simply require my images once mapped.

Thanks.

Comment: When you import single images without MobX, does it work in production?